# VueJS - after npm run build I got blank page

Tags: npm, build, vue.js

After I run "npm run build", I got this tip in the console:

Build complete.

Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.
  Opening index.html over file:// won't work.

In my local server, npm run dev works fine, but after upload the project on Apache server, installed node_modules (npm install) and I run "npm run build", I got the tip in the console and a blank page, no errors in dev console in my browser

The path on the server (Apache) is: /mydomainproject/public/projects files:

```
build
config
dist
node_modules
src
static
.babelrc
.editorconfig
.postcssrc.js
index.html
package.json
package-lock.json
.htaccess
```

This is my public/config/index.js

```
build: {
    // Template for index.html
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),

    // Paths
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
```

I've changed assetsPublicPath: '/' to assetsPublicPath: './', also I tried assetsPublicPath: './public', but still not work.

Please, someone can help me?

Thanks!

Now I'm really scared, I'm building a web app using Vue version 2.5.2 on local server and everything working fine after run "npm run dev", but after run build on production server (Apache) I got blank page... nobody knows about this problem... I've changed config/index.js, adding relative paths, ./, /, even absolute path (I never work with absolute paths), I've asked in Github forum, no answers... Also, there are no errors in the console log browser.

Comment: What if you change `assetsPublicPath: '/',` to `assetsPublicPath: './',`

Comment: Yes, I did, and run npm run build again, still not work. Thanks!

Comment: Reload your app and check your log again. It should work. In any case you are not supposed to use absolute path `/` when building in webpack, you have to use relative path

Comment: Well, I did that, no errors in the log, what missing?...

Comment: Also make sure that your server(MAMP/XAMP, etc) is pointing to the `dist` folder created by `npm run build`

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you're using the [webpack template for vue cli](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack), which is what it looks like, this should help. The reason this may be useful to know the difference on is if you were to use the [webpack-simple template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple), it has a single `webpack-config.js` file, with the direct use of the [`publicPath` property from webpack](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-publicpath) (as opposed to `assetsPublicPath`).

A little while back I ran into what seemed to be the same situation. This seemed to be due to my use of the local dev server `npm run dev` instantiating things at a root level to my local dev server, as opposed to my production path, which was a sub-directory on the server. I solved it by changing the `assetsPublicPath` property that you've mentioned working with, only for the `build` config in `config/index.js`.

The setting of `assetsPublicPath` to an empty string should make the build respect path relative network assets. It's similar to the difference of writing `<script src="/path/to/my.js"></script>` (absolute to the server) and `<script src="relative/path/to/my.js"></script>` (relative to the html file the script tag is defined in).

Here's what my config looks like as a snippet.

```javascript
// config/index.js
...
module.exports = {
  build: {
    ...
    assetsPublicPath: '',
    ...
  },
  dev: {
    ...
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using Webpack template for Vue CLI. I've tried your suggestion, doesn't work, it's frustrating. I have another project built with Vue 2.1.0, there is not "config/index.js" and working fine on the same server, now I'm using Vue version 2.5.2. I wouldn't like back to the old version... Any idea?
Thanks anyway!

Comment: The `config/index.js` should be the one you mentioned as your `public/config/index.js` that includes some configuration info for your build (and dev) execution.

Comment: @EricMcCormick Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL / from this server.  this error is for docker not able to serve the via httpserver for index.html?

Comment: @LOG_TAG a forbidden error is going to be a server configuration issue. The question, and answer, above have everything to do with front end asset build configuration, per the vue cli, and nothing to do with server responses. It sounds like you know its related to being served via a configuration within a docker setup, so it seems to me that your issue is likely to be its own question and answer. If you've got the specifics in an SO question somewhere, I can look; otherwise best of luck!

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps the simplest way to solve the issue is to create a file `vue.config.js` in the project's root directory and add to it the following code:

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: ''
}
```

In my situation, this solved the problem. Source of information: see [here](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/310#issuecomment-592251968).

Answer (score 6):

I searched forever with this same issue (npm run dev worked but build had a blank page).

The assetsPublicPath can be updated in the /config/index.js file if your project will end up on a server in a subfolder. But, what finally worked for me was that I was using `mode: 'history'` in my router setup.  This had no problems during dev but in build it would not work.

There are more details listed here about configuring your server to [work with history mode here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html). But I didn't want to mess with server settings at the moment and if I didn't use history mode then it instantly worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem and did not get a black page when I removed `mode: 'history'` in `vue-router` (as Dean mentioned).

From VueJs documentation:

> .... To fix the issue, all you need to do is add a simple catch-all fallback route to your server. If the URL doesn't match any static assets, it should serve the same index.html page that your app lives in. (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-history-mode)

So, all you need to do to enable history mode is add a catch-all route:

```
{
   path: '*',
   name: 'catchAll',
   component: Home
}
```

**NOTE**: this catch-all route should go at the bottom -- after all other routes (otherwise, all requests will go to it).

Answer (score 0):

i solve my issue by create a vue.config.js file on the root directory

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/dist/'
    : '/'
}
```

note: change */dist/* to the folder name where your static files are

then `npm run build`

i checked it using the live server of vscode and it works

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue too. My main.js was like this:

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  router,
  })
}).$mount('#app')
```

The "vm" variable was never used in my main.js.
I thought webpack excluded unused variables.
So I initialized "new Vue" without assigning it to the variable.
And problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

So I have had this error for a while, I tried all the proposed solutions above but none seemed to work.
Then I noticed that in development, there was a "you may have an infinite update loop in a component render function" warning, which I had been ignoring, after fixing the component, npm run build started to work well.

I hope this helps somebody

Comment: How is this related?

Comment: This was the exact issue that I had, npm run build showing a blank screen, but it was because Vue was throwing a critical error as a warning in development, the blank screen issue can also be caused by an error in your code... that's my point

Answer (score 0):

I am using Vue 3, and ran into this problem after running `"npm run build"`. To fix it on my production server (Bitnami LAMP stack on Ubuntu through AWS lightsail), I had to change two lines in the generated production index.html, found in: (./dist/index.html)
In that file, I had to prepend a '.' on the src and href attributes in the script and link elements.

My script tag declaration specifically looks like this after editing:
`<script type="module" crossorigin src="./assets/index.4a1f78d4.js">`

As a side note that may be relevant to others, using npm's serve, `serve -s dist` from the project root to test deployment did not properly duplicate my bitnami Apapche 2 server environment. Specifically, testing this way did not reveal the fact that I needed to alter the file paths within index.html, I found this out when testing on my actual server.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is using vite (From the same source as @RomanKaragodin): 
Add `base: "./"` to your vite.config.js.